# Connecting a supercapacitor to a supply with voltage lesser than capacitor's rated voltage

Tags: capacitor, supercapacitor, coin-cell

I am connecting a 3V power supply (CR2032/CR2450 coin cell) to a 1.5F 5.5V rated supercap. Given that the supply voltage is lesser than rated voltage of supercap, chances of any damage become minimal. But my doubt is: whether this setup would increase the quiescent current drawn by supercap and hence decrease the battery capacity.

Theoretically, i suspect it shouldn't make any difference but in a test circuit I observed quiescent current was higher than what was provided in supercap datasheet (when battery and supercap had reached the same voltage).

Comment: What are your actual numbers?

Comment: 6uA is what datasheet specifies as quiescent current, i am observing around 200uA, although there's a possibility which i am considering is that my current measurement instrument might be faulty. But speaking purely theoretically, should this happen?

Comment: Link to data sheet please.

Comment: Datasheet : https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/212/1/KEM_S6019_FE-1103433.pdf

Comment: I don't see the 6 uA in the data sheet - what page is it on?

Comment: apologies for the confusion the datasheet is : https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/40/AVX-SCM-6.0V-1221003.pdf
Disclaimer: I had to source this from a local vendor and I am not sure if this is original or could be knock-off

Comment: @Andyaka i have posted my whole problem statement at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/501616/253198. Please see if you can help me on this.

Comment: @mosdkr in that replacement data sheet it is a 6 volt part and not the 5.5 volt part originally in your question. So, what page does it say 6 uA? Please don't point me to other questions, when this is still active - where is the 6 uA stated? What page?

Comment: Please check this: https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/40/AVX-SCM-1018838.pdf
Page 2 : exact specs are 5V and 10uA
Apologies for so many edits

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you've let the capacitor soak for the time mentioned on the datasheet or application data. For example, AVX specifies the leakage as 10uA *after 72 hours*.

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, this can be the issue, the values I quoted in the question are taken at around 1 hour. In that case can you confirm that afters 72 hours I should observe similar values as per the datasheet and "supply voltage<rated voltage" should not be an issue

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: However, given the datasheet you linked, the datasheet specification seems to be <2.3mA after 30 minutes.  Where is the 6uA stated?

Comment: Hi Spehro can you please see if you can help me with this : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/501616/253198

Comment: Please check this: mouser.in/datasheet/2/40/AVX-SCM-1018838.pdf Page 2 : exact specs are 5V and 10uA Apologies for so many edits
Disclaimer: I had to source this from a local vendor and I am not sure if this is original or could be knock-off