# Powering a RF circuit with CR2032 along a capacitor, pulse currents of 150mA

Tags: battery-charging, battery-operated, supercapacitor, batteries, coin-cell

I am designing a battery powered circuit which performs RF communication. The goal is to use a 3V CR2032 battery. The RF circuit consumes 0.2mA as average current and lowest voltage it can work on is 2.8V. This average current is broken into various pulse current draws which are as follows:

- WAKES UP
- 8mA for 2ms
- 15mA for 1.5ms
- [90mA for 0.2ms,15mA for 0.3ms,150mA for 0.2ms] X 4 times
- Deep Sleep with current of 20uA

The part in bracket (step 4) happens 4 times as 4 Tx/Rx cycles. The circuit is doing this at every 2 secs. I am trying to put a capacitor so that these pulse currents can be taken care by a supercap. As per my calculations:

For an average current of 0.2mA, assuming we need capacitor to store enough power for 5 secs,
Charge required in capacitor = 0.00028mAh = 1mC

Using C=Q/V at 3.1V,
C = 1mC/3.1V = **0.32mF**

I am planning to use a **330ohm** resistor so the charging times comes to be:
T=5*R*C = 5*330*0.32mF = **0.53 secs**

Questions:

1. Are the above calculations and assumptions correct?
2. I tried using a 1.5F capacitor but the performance was dismal, there was a continuous draw which started at 200uA and gradually went upto 1000uA bringing the voltage of battery<2.8V, I am assuming this is because the capacitor wasn't getting enough time to get charged.
3. Please propose any better alternatives

Battery Datasheet : https://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/596824/PANASONICBATTERY/CR2032.html

Capacitor Datasheet : https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/40/AVX-SCM-1018838.pdf
Version used by me works at Vmax of 5V and has quiescent current of 10uA, to be on safer side of calculations I am assuming 15uA

Comment: yes makes sense, the dropout voltage for circuit is 2.8V that makes it operate almost at the edge, but then I was thinking to put multiple CR2032 to get more capacity in the small voltage range I have. I am trying to prevent using a boost convertor to keep the circuit simpler and avoid any further current draws

Comment: sorry missed the lower voltage earlier, please see that you cannot make your circuit work lower, I can flat out tell you it will not be able to use more than 50% of the battery capacity under those conditions,

Comment: yes I am considering that and have accepted that I won't be able to utilise the whole battery and would try to compensate by either putting a higher mAh battery like CR2450 or use multiple CR2032 cells. Do you think I should put a boost convertor

Comment: It is not an issue with the capacity, it is an issue with the voltage and ESR inherent to these size batteries, you fall below 2.8V under small loads due to the batteries own discharge curve around 50%

Comment: assuming I utilise only 50% capacity of my battery pack, would the calculations for capacitor hold true? If they are I will probably think of putting a boost regulator

Comment: at 3V, you can only use the charge in the capacitor between 3V and 2.8V, so your voltage for the equation would actually be 0.2V, as this battery voltage falls, it contributes less and less,

Comment: Combined with this, the energy that needs to be stored in the capacitor during the Transmission is 364uAs if we ignore the idle current, as that will not really come into play for how much capacitance you need

Comment: so for that capacitance comes around 432uF, I will check with a test circuit and quote the results here, I am bit confused though because till the time battery voltage drops below 2.8v the capacitor would still be at a voltage in 2.8-3.1V and will deliver current at this voltage only. And given the RF circuit needs a power @avg current of 0.2mA it still should require the same amount of power

Comment: I might try two cells in *series* followed by a linear regulator with ultra low Iq (I know of some with around 500nA Iq at low load) - the output of the regulator might need a fair amount of hold up capacitance but it would not be anywhere close to what your current approach is.

Comment: Battery data sheet and capacitor data sheets are required. Please provide links to the PDF documents.

Comment: @Andyaka i have edited the question to add the two datasheets

Comment: @PeterSmith sounds good I will try this out in a test circuit. Do you think using the same battery of 3v but with a boost converter will be better(capacitor too will be connected)? I am seeing >90% efficiency in most of the boost converters available online, low cost ones too. And they seem to operate as low as 1.8V

Comment: @mosdkr - by my calculation, you are operating at a duty cycle of around 0.15% and in a situation like this, the power consumed by a regulator has to be carefully considered. In these cases, a linear regulator often yields longer battery life. Be careful of the efficiency rating of converters; that will be at only one point in the transfer function where you may not be operating. At very low load currents the efficiency is often very low ( < 50% in many cases). At 20uA load, it will probably be a *lot* less.

Comment: Thanks @PeterSmith for this valuable input, I wasn't considering this

Comment: @PeterSmith I will start testing with linear regulator, but continuing on your previous note, given there will be a capacitor between the linear regulator and the power drawing circuit, as soon as capacitor discharges it will start drawing current again and on average we will see a constant current draw from the regulator much higher than 20uA and probably around 0.2mA which is the average draw of the circuit, would I still face the problem of too low a current affecting regulator efficiency

Comment: @mosdkr -- whether the current is drawn from the output of the regulator or the output capacitor, the total *power* will be the same. If you can tolerate a load transient of around 0.1V, then this device *may* be suitable. https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps783.pdf There are many options to choose from now.

Comment: @PeterSmith thank you very much this is extremely helpful

Comment: @PeterSmith I was wondering if the supercap to provide pulse currents to the RF circuit should be put before the linear regulator or after it. If i put it before it will be at 6V (from 2 series CR2032) and will provide more time and more charge for powering the circuit and if i put it after the regulator, the regulator will not have to go through the pulse currents. Which is better and do regulators perform well and efficiently if they have to draw and supply pulse currents?